# Variables (column names) differ between power bi and power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, data-cleaning

I have powerbi report and the power query looks like below. What would be the reason why the column names are not coming right? many thanks in advance.

[image: power query]

[image: powerbi]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible reason is that the query is not successfully refreshing and loading into Power BI so you're still seeing the old data and column names.